# Tikz: text containing formulas and symbols following a given curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I have already been searching for this some time, but unfortunately I cannot find an answer. 
I am trying to write some text that is following a given curve. As long as I do not use math mode that works out fine. However, I need some formulas resp. symbols in that text too, so, is there a way to obtain that?
It should be something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [decorate,decoration={text along path,
        text={$t\rightarrow t_0$}}]
        (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0) sin (7,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There is of course some more text coming, but just to give an idea...

Comment: `text along path` works by placing every character piece-by-piece. In your case, it tries to place the `$`, `t`, `\rightarrow`, `t`, `_`, `0` and `$` on their own. This won’t work. You need to split it up manually like I did in [How do I make my path node follow the path from a certain position?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132417) Try something like `text={$t$} {$\rightarrow$} {$t_0$}`.

Answer (score 5):

The `text along path` decorations works by placing the text character for character. In your case, it tries to place the characters `$`, `t`, `\rightarrow`, `t`, `_`, `0` and `$` on their own. This will lead to many errors (`$` without a closing `$`, math-mode stuff in text-mode).

You will need to split the “text” up in its contents (the spacing provided by math-mode will be lost but this decoration isn’t made for that anyway).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{
  text deco/.style={
    postaction={decorate, decoration={text along path, #1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[
    text deco={raise=5pt, text align={align=left, left indent=11em},
      text={$t$} {$\rightarrow$} {$t_0$}},
    text deco={raise=5pt, text align={align=left, left indent=15.5em},
      text={$t$} {$\rightarrow$} {$t_0$}},
    text deco={raise=-5pt,
    text=|\color{gray}|........................%
         |+\bfseries|........................%
         |\color{blue!50}|.............................................}
  ]
    (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0) sin (7,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I think we need curved \to here. (I have no backticks on my iPad)