# \texttt in decoration causes LaTeX to hang

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \path [->,decorate,decoration={raise=-5pt, text along path,
   text={\texttt{foo}}, text align=center, text color=red}] (0,0) -- (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Attempting to compile it seems to result in some infinite loop. If I take out the `\texttt` it works (although not yielding what I'd expect). Why?

Comment: What do you expect?!

Comment: I expect the `\path` command with the `->` option to draw a line from (0,0) to (5,5), which it does not, even if replaced by `\draw`. But that is not the question here.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136153/tikz-text-containing-formulas-and-symbols-following-a-given-curve This explains why your command can't work.

Comment: `text={|\ttfamily|foo ||}` will get you typewriter text. Do you want the text to be stretched along the line, appear somewhere along the line or do something else?

Comment: Eventually, it should curve alongside an arrow, but I'm not that far yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples which may help. The first three use the same decoration. The fourth uses another text decoration where things are handled a little differently.

- You need to use `|` to delimit formatting commands when using `text along path`.
- You need to decorate as a `postaction` if you want the path to be drawn or whatever rather than replaced by the text.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Here the text decoration replaces the path completely so it will not be drawn even if you add draw
  % The | makes it possible to pass formatting commands to the decoration
  \path [->, decorate, decoration={raise=-5pt, text along path, text={|\ttfamily|foo ||}, text align=center, text color=red}] (0,0) -- (5,5);
  % postaction=decorate tells TiKZ to decorate the path *after* drawing it
  \path [->, draw, postaction=decorate, decoration={raise=-10pt, text along path, text={|\ttfamily|foo ||}, text align=center, text color=blue}] (0,-1) -- (5,4);
  % Here the text is stretched out along the path
  \path [decoration={text along path, text={|\ttfamily|foo ||}, text align=fit to path}, postaction=decorate, draw, ->] (0,-2) -- (5,3);
  % Here is a fancier one which scales the characters so that the text 'grows' along the path
  \path [decoration={text effects along path, text={foo}, text effects/.cd, color=green!50!black, character count=\i, character total=\n, characters={text along path, scale=\i/\n, font=\ttfamily}}, postaction=decorate, draw, ->]  (0,-3) -- (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: 4 decorated paths]

Answer (score 2):

The characters are typeset one by one in a box; formatting instructions should be added between `|`, see the manual, section 48.6, page 603.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \path [->,decorate,decoration={raise=-5pt, text along path,
   text={|\ttfamily|foo bar}, text align=center, text color=red}] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]