# \'e is ending the path code, Poupees

Tags: xetex, accents

This is a small snippet of the code. If I remove the \'e and replace it with an e it works fine, but not I want to print a special character (the e with an accent). Moreover, \'e is working on other pages where it is not nested. How can I find a workaround for that:

```
\path[postaction={
    decorate,decoration={
        text along path,text align=center, text={
            |\engl\fontsize{22pt}{22}\selectfont\color{white}\hspace*{-0.3mm}|“Poup\'ees et bonbons},raise=-1pt}
            }](-12mm, -47mm)to[bend left=55] (132mm, -47mm){};
```

Comment: Please, make the example compilable.

Comment: misclicked latex3 sorry about that

Comment: probably you need `{\'e}` so the macro can split up the text  letter by letter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i actually thought about that but didnt try it, make sure to test it that way, i hope it works. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle placing the {} as {\’e} works perfectly, thank you very much, i wont place it as an answer so that you get the point for that :D

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136153/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `{\'e}` so the macro can split up the text letter by letter.